# 404 after moving localhost wp to server

Tags: 404-error

I am moving my WordPress installation on `localhost` to a test server, which doesn't have WordPress installed.

- exported my database as SQL and replaced `http://localhost/wordpress` with `http://mydomain.myserver.com/wordpress`, then imported it to the server
- copied my WordPress folder into Apache server, with same folder name and proper access rights
- deleted `.htaccess` file and flushed permalinks

I am able to access admin pages without a problem, but everything on the site including home page is giving `404`. What more can I try to solve it?

Additional info:

- I wrote a simple theme myself and it's working on `localhost` properly, don't know if it may affect the `404` error I'm getting.
- `localhost` is Windows and the server is CentOS.
- apache `mod_rewrite` seems to be enabled

Comment: `localhost is Windows and the server is CentOS`. Please describe this distinctly. `CentOS` is not a server.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **query monitor** plugin, remove **.db** file from **wp-content** folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your database URLs:

- Upload local database
- Go to your live database, find a table called: wp_options
- Replace the siteurl and the home with your new URLs (live), e.g. http://www.myliveurl.com/

You should be all set.

Comment: they are same and both seems to be correct, they are like http://www.myliveurl.com/wordpress, and on the localhost http://localhost/wordpress so /wordpress part must be correct

Comment: With http://myliveurl.com/wordpress ?

If you can login to the backend, goto: Setting | Permalinks | And refresh your permalinks (generate a new htaccess). Try this without the clean URLs – first option

Comment: it works when I change it to first permalink option, doesn't work with second option :/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It could be: 
- File permissions on your .htaccess file - check that you have write permissions

Comment: Also check that you have Apache mod_rewrite enabled. Check with your web hosting provider, or you can add this piece of code to your index.php in your WordPress theme to view your Apache / Php settings: <? phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: when I delete htaccess and refresh permalinks, wp can create a new htaccess file so it has write rights. Mod rewrite is listed in phpinfo() too. First permalink option works, second doesn't so its on first for now but 2nd would be better.

Comment: have you tried to check these lines in the `wp-config'

Comment: define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/wordpress');